# textview showing correct in design and incorrect in emulator

Tags: java, android

Hi I am new in andriod and this is my first app but i got problem when I am trying to add textview it is appearing correct in andriod design but incorrect in emulator and there is no error in program.so help me fix this
[Here is the screenshot of my problem``](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv5kR.jpg)

I tried to change the api and theme but it didn't work
code MainActivity.java

```
   package amitkumar.helloworld;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
   import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="amitkumar.helloworld.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="377dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="380dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.444"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="379dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="287dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
    android:text="@string/textview"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.888"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    tools:text="This is My First Project"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your TextView text like this `android:text="This is My First Project"` instead of this `android:text="@string/textview` and delete line `tools:text="This is My First Project"`

Comment: Thanks it worked and I needed to add this   ` tools:ignore="HardcodedText" `

Answer (score 0):

For showing your XML content at run time use **android:** namespace.

```
android:text="Will be shown at runtime"
```

By using **tools:** namespace you will only be able to see content in android studio's preview.

```
tools:text="Just to show in preview"
```

Answer (score 0):

tools:text="toolsText" is used for Android Studio layout preview

android:text="androidText" is used to set text to a a layout element